# Tanuki Service Wrapper display access

Tags: selenium, vnc, java-service-wrapper, tanuki

I have a simple Java application that is using the [Tanuki Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) that loads [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) for me.  Everything works find when I execute things using `./myapp console` as the user that owns the application and the VNC server.

However, after setting the `RUN_AS_USER` in the Tanuki setup and setting the `DISPLAY` variable in `/etc/environment` and all the profiles in Ubuntu 16.04, my Java application cannot access the display.

I installed VNC on Ubuntu 16.04 using [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I can run xeyes, xterm, etc. as any user after running `xhost +` and I ensure that the command runs on startup of the vncserver.

What happens is I get stuck on the following log message before I finally hit a timeout:

> jvm 1    | Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e) on port 32655
>
> jvm 1    | Only local connections are allowed.

I also tried editing the `/etc/chromium-browser/default` file to include the "--display :1" specification in the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` option as was suggested in other posts with no luck.

The other option I have seen suggested was in the Java code to add, but this did not work:

```
webDriver.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":1");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues in Ubuntu for the same purpose.  We wound up switching to a RHEL 7 instance with TigerVNC.

We were under the gun to get something accomplished and wound up actually sticking with it as there were no issues, even during an upgrade.  I tried following the instructions you provided and had the same issue.  The ones I followed for RHEL were very similar and can be found here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-TigerVNC.html

You may want to try using TigerVNC on Ubuntu instead.

Comment: I'll try with TigerVNC.  Switching from TightVNC shouldn't be much of an issue.  I'll let you know how it goes or try the RHEL solution.